# Problema com estrutura de repetição while

Tags: python, while

Fiz esse pequeno código para que ele pedisse um usuário e uma senha. Caso os dados fossem iguais aos definidos dentro do código, mostrar um "sucesso", caso o user esteja diferente do que é colocado no código, pedir novamente o user.

Tentei usar a estrutura de repetição while, mas não estou usando corretamente.

```
import getpass

user = str(input('Usuário: '))
def login():
    while(user!='admin'):
    user = str(input('Usuário: '))

if (user=='admin'):
    passwd = getpass.getpass('Senha: ') 
else:
    login()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi a pergunta, mas vamos lá:

[Veja o código rodando no rel.it.](https://repl.it/IqxM/2)

```
import getpass

def login():
    usr = 'Admin'
    while True:
        user = str(input('Usuário: '))
        if user != usr:
            print('Usuário inválido')
        else:
            print ('Senha: ')
            getpass.getpass('Senha: ')
            print ('ok')
            break

login()        

Usuário:  afasdfasf
Usuário inválido
Usuário:  Admin
Senha: 
 master
ok
```

[DEMO](https://repl.it/IqxM/2)

Comment: Seu código repete Senha: duas vezes depois que é digitado o user e teclado enter, mas foi bem interessante. Vou dá uma estudada!

Comment: Fiz assim pq em alguns consoles o getpass fica "invisivel", inclusive onde eu postei o codigo.

Answer (score 1):

```
import getpass

user = str(input('Usuário: ')) # user é variavel global
def login(): # user não existe dentro de login()
    while(user!='admin'): 
    user = str(input('Usuário: ')) # essa linha deveria estar identada pra ficar dentro do loop while

if (user=='admin'):
    passwd = getpass.getpass('Senha: ') 
else:
    login()
```

Fiz alguns comentarios pontuais no seu código original, abaixo está o código que eu imagino que vc tenha tentado fazer.

```
import getpass

user = str(input('Usuário: '))
def login(user): # user passado por parametro pra poder ser acessado dentro da função
    while(user!='admin'):
        user = str(input('Usuário: ')) # informação dentro do loop while identada corretamente
if (user=='admin'):
    passwd = getpass.getpass('Senha: ') 
else:
    login(user) # variavel user sendo passada por parametro pra função login.
    passwd = getpass.getpass('Senha: ') # recebe passwd após sair da função
```

Imagino que o resultado final seria esse. Perceba que se o objetivo eh printar na tela a string `Senha:` antes do usuário inserir a senha, vc terá que fazer algo como o @Sidon fez, pois a função getpass.getpass não printa a string passada por parâmetro.

Comment: Analisei os comentários que fez no meu código e percebi alguns erros que cometi. Seu código foi bastante útil!